# Clean Angular 11 Component Inheritance Architecture with Separate Templates

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I am trying to setup an architecture in Angular 11 where I create an interface for a component, create an abstract Base Class for the component which takes care of non-template specific logic, then allow subclasses (only one level lower for the foreseeable future) to implement the html + css template and any additional logic specific to that.

**Problem Statement**

I cannot find a way to satisfy the above requirements in a clean and maintainable fashion.  The next section outlines more details, the following sections outline attempted solutions.

**Architecture**

I am creating a common library which will house multiple versions of the same controls to be reusable within different contexts, such as different websites or different themes for a website.  I will be using an abstract-factory-like pattern; all *Control-Kits* are required to implement the same controls and behave the same in terms of *Input* and *Output* + *events*.  The consumer can request a certain *Control-Kit* via the Angular module imports (Controls module will have a static *provide* method, which is where the abstract factory comes in) or some sort of strategy pattern if dynamic change is required.

Each component has roughly three steps, the last step is where each *Controls-Kit* is responsible for its own presentation.

1. Component interface definition: declare the input and output (@Input and @Output) properties, as normal fields without decorators.
2. Abstract component base class: implement the fields with @Input and @Output decorators and handle *ngOnChanges* events accordingly.
3. Extend the component for each *Controls-Kit* and declare the html + css templates for this particular kit.

**Inheritance with Angular Properties**

I am facing an issue with taking this approach when using @Input and @Output decorators in base classes.  Angular is throwing errors when running commands *build* or *serve* that it does not recognize the particular properties I am trying to set / listen to (such as value, change, and other custom properties).  I have read online that Angular *may or may not* support this type of properties w/ inheritance, depending upon which soure you read.  I have attempted decorating the base class with *Directive, Injectable, Component* as well, none have worked.  I have tried the following solutions; all fail except for the last, but I would prefer to avoid the last for reasons I will specify.

**Failed Solution: Declare Properties with Decorators In Base Classes**

This is esentially what I've described above; declare the properties with decorators in the base class.  This actually does seem to function when I publish the library as an npm package, then use in an external solution, but it causes build/serve failures when running in its own local project.  I do not want to leave as is because this may cause breaking changes down the line, plus I cannot re-use this type of pattern in any other project which will be its own application (not a library).

This is an example of this attempted solution:

```
//@Directive() (others also did not work)
export abstract class BaseStarInputComponent implements iStarInputComponent, OnChanges, iAbstractComponent {

    @Input(StarInputAttributes.numStars) numStars: number = 5;
    @Input(StarInputAttributes.disabled) disabled: boolean = false;
    @Input(StarInputAttributes.value) value: number = 5;
    @Input(StarInputAttributes.stepValue) stepValue: number = 1;
    @Output(StarInputAttributes.change) change: EventEmitter<iStarInputComponentValueChanged> = new EventEmitter<iStarInputComponentValueChanged>();

    private isFirstValueChange = true;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.doNgOnInit();
    }
    abstract doNgOnInit(): void;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.numStars) {
            if (changes.numStars.isFirstChange()) {
                this.numStars = changes.numStars.currentValue;
            } else if (changes.numStars.currentValue !== changes.numStars.previousValue) {
                throw new Error(`Changing number of stars after initial assignment is not yet supported!`);
            }
        }

        if (changes.value) {
            this.setValue(changes.value.currentValue, changes.value.previousValue);
        }

        if (changes.stepValue) {
            this.stepValue = changes.stepValue.currentValue;
            this.setValue(this.value);
        }
    }
    
    setValue(newValue: number, oldValue?: number): void {
        if (typeof oldValue === 'undefined') {
            oldValue = this.value;
        }

        if (typeof newValue === 'undefined') {
            newValue = oldValue;
        }

        if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined') {
            newValue = newValue - newValue % this.stepValue;

            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                this.value = newValue;
                this.change.emit({
                    oldValue,
                    newValue,
                    isFirstChange: this.isFirstValueChange
                });
                this.isFirstValueChange = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Failed Solution: Create a Class Decorator Which Alters the Prototype**

In this attempt, I've created a class decorator of my own which will alter the constructor's prototype to include the properties, such as this:

```
export function StarInputComponentDecorator(constructorFunction: Function) {
    constructorFunction.prototype.numStars = Input(StarInputAttributes.numStars)(5);
    constructorFunction.prototype.disabled = Input(StarInputAttributes.disabled)(false);
    constructorFunction.prototype.value = Input(StarInputAttributes.value)(5);
    constructorFunction.prototype.stepValue = Input(StarInputAttributes.stepValue)(1);
    constructorFunction.prototype.change = Output(StarInputAttributes.change)(new EventEmitter<iStarInputComponentValueChanged>());
    return constructorFunction;
}

@Component({
  selector: StarInputComponentSelector,
  templateUrl: './star-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./star-input.component.scss']
})
@StarInputComponentDecorator
export class StarInputComponent extends BaseStarInputComponent {}
```

**Partially Successful Solution: Redeclare Properties Everywhere**

The program will build+serve if I re-declare all input and output properties in all extended classes.  However, I would prefer to avoid this solution, as it violates the *DRY* principle and can lead to bugs in situations where *Controls-Kits* factories are changed or swapped out.  Additionally, if any refactoring is required, it will require updates to many files instead of just one.

**Final Solutions?**

I have created this post to see if anyone either knows of any solution such as the one above (modified to work, of course), or of any alternative solutions that will still allow for static compilation.  I feel that the decorator approach (#2) may be the best way to go but I have been unable to make it work myself.  I may be missing some metadata which the decorator function can return to declare that the prototype now has those properties.

Please let me know what you think.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you give example of the errors you're getting with the first approach. I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. In my experience, angular doesn't have problems recognizing such properties, as seen in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhy4ka?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I realized the issue, I believe I was doing something inconsistently between the different base components.  Using @Directive across all of them, verifying everything, and re serving seems to have worked.  Thanks!